# Communication between 2 API services on the same cluster not working

Tags: api, kubernetes

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster with 2 API services inside Upon makin a API call to to my web-API located in the cluster I want the call to be forwarded to my  backend-API.

This is not happening!

Now I looked into the the Ingress config of the backend-API and found its "Out side address" so to say and tried using that when forwarding API calls from the web-API upon which I received this message (This was a https address.

```
THE API CALL RESPONSE WAS: StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.0, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Server: squid/3.1.23
  Mime-Version: 1.0
  Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 23:00:54 GMT
  X-Squid-Error: ERR_DNS_FAIL 0
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 3525
}
```

Then I did some reading and got convinced I should send the internal API call to the backend using its internal IP. So executed in to the container running the backend service and viewed the resolv.config file and here I found 2 things one was a name: which was followed by a IP address and the other was Search: which was followed by 3 very long names.

So I used the IP address that came after name and upon sending a API call to it I got the following response:

```
http://10.233.0.3/uploadBlob
THE API CALL RESPONSE WAS: StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.0, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Server: squid/3.1.23
  Mime-Version: 1.0
  Date: Sun, 24 Oct 2021 15:59:51 GMT
  X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
  X-Cache: MISS from **************
  X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from **************:8080
  Via: 1.0 ************* (squid/3.1.23)
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 3458
}

http://10.233.0.3/uploadBlob
```

OBS - I had to remove the addresses for security reasons as I am not the owner of it.

Now I'm all out of ideas as to how I can make this internal call between these two services and i would appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: What Kubernetes version do you use? is it on cloud or bare-metal?